# If my site is hosted on my own existing host provider, and I switch to wordpress theme, do I have to transfer every file?

Tags: wordpress

I have a site with about 15 pages of content, and some 50 pages of php scripts. They are all hosted on my existing hosting which I had for a long time.

What I want to do is use a wordpress template. What will happen to the files on my current hosting? Can they stay as they are? And is the wordpress template essentially just css and some images?

Thanks!

Comment: you're switching from something custom -> pure wordpress? or wordpress->wordpress? But generally, yeah. if you're moving a site, you have to move everything. It'd be like "I'm walking to the store. Do I have to take my arms/legs/face along, or can I leave them home?"

Comment: @MarcB I am moving from custom to wordpress.  But I don't want to move the hosting nor the php, nor my domain.  I just want to change the site design.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to convert the existing site to a working [Wordpress theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

Existing pages can be made into [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates).

If you are using custom functions, etc, you can include them into Functions.php.

Once you have a working theme, install Wordpress on the site's root directory and activate the theme.